# Windows 8: Html markup not showing on page

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am new to Windows 8 development, and am going the Html/Javascript route. I have started out with the Grid template.

Why when I add,

Test Content

.. to the content area html (not the item template html) in the body, does the text Test Content not show on the page when I start the project?

Ex.

```
    </head>
```

```
<div>Test Content</div>

<!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
<div class="groupdetailpage fragment">
    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pagetitle"></span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <div>Test Content</div>
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <div class="itemslist win-selectionstylefilled" title="Test Content" aria-label="List of this group's items" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ selectionMode: 'none' }"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

suggest refer default.css, and read up on grid layout (display: -ms-grid)

```
.fragment {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 128px 1fr;
    display: -ms-grid;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

.groupdetailpage.fragment takes 100% width, height and hence, the test content div outside fragment is not visible.

```
.fragment header[role=banner] {
    // since -ms-grid-row is not defined, this element takes row 1
    /* Define a grid with columns for the back button and page title. */
    -ms-grid-columns: 39px 81px 1fr auto;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
    display: -ms-grid;
}

.fragment section[role=main] 
{
    -ms-grid-row: 2;
}
```

.groupdetailpage.fragment has display has -ms-grid. hence, the .header and section[role=main] only are visible which occupy row 1, and 2 respectively.

changing section like this will make test content div visible.

```
<section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
    <div>Test Content</div>
</section>
```

reading up on grid layout will help since that is very key to winjs based windows store app development.

Comment: Thanks @Sushil. I moved the Test Content div inside the 'main' section, as in your last code snippet, still the text did not appear. Based on your feedback, I am looking into restructuring my grid to include a row for the back button and page title.

Comment: need to carefully see other children in the element. other child  might be overlapping. other debugging tool that helps is the DOM explorer under vs debug menu->windows->dom explorer. it is visible only after debugging is started. you can use `select element` to see the dom elements and their css.